# Define numbering for numbered list item on a lower level

Tags: google-docs, google-workspace-for-business

I have a document with several headings and subheadings that shall be numbered. The numbering style is supposed to be as follows:

```
1.  Heading

[paragraph] 

    1.1  Subheading

[paragraph]

2.  Heading

[paragraph]
```

However, since I added the numbering option afterwards, google docs does not recognise my headings as being part of one and the same list, but starts the numbering a new for every (sub)heading:

[image: picture of sample document with wrong numbering]

Now, I do know how to change the number of a specific item in a numbered list in order to match its place:

[image]

[image]

However, what I do not know is, how I can change it for my subheading:

[image]

when I try it the same way I did with the second heading, it will not recognise my input as being a valid one:

[image]

---

How can I either make docs recognise all my headings as being part of the same list, or restart the numbering for an item on a "lower hierarchy level"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, from the "Numbered list" drop-down menu, choose the right format for you, numbers/letters etc.

The number 1 was printed before the text,
use the "tab" key from your keyboard
to push the next line to be 1.1  instead of 2, 
the next Enter key will print 1.2

Answer (score 0):

One way of making it work is:

1. Make numbering of Headings as you explained
2. Place cursor in front of your to_be_subheading, use the "tab" key to make a correct indent and then number it as you need same as you did with heading (restart numbering to 2 instead of default number 1 if it is a subheading of heading 2, etc.)
3. last step is giving suffix to your subheading. You do that this way, mark the current number of your to_be_subheading then go to Format->Bullets and numbering->List options->Edit prefix and suffix. Choose no prefix, and place wanted suffix in the suffix input field. You should see the correct heading number before the suffix field.

There you go! :) 
I hope I have helped.